# how to configure the launch.json in VS code to accept a network path (python) in windows

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

I have been given the following network path to a `python` exe (in `windows10`):

```
\\eu\tac\conda\1.0\win\envs\dev\CURRENT\python.exe
```

Note the single and double `\`'s in the above path.

i try to edit the `launch.json` in `vscode` to include this as follows:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: network (not working)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "\\eu\\tac\\conda\\1.0\\win\\envs\\dev\\CURRENT\\python.exe",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true

        }
    ]
}
```

However, i keep getting errors either referring to invalid syntax which presumably come from the `\` and `/` variants that i have tried. Or a `No such file or directory: 'H:\\eu\\tac\\conda\\1.0\\win\\envs\\dev\\CURRENT\\python.exe'` error message as the terminal adds an `H:` prior to the program.

So the question is, how can i get `vscode` to recognise the path correctly ?

Comment: will the path work if typed on the command line, then use `\\\\eu\\tac\\.....`, 4 backslash at the beginning

Comment: i tried that and it threw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i have discovered is that the `"program": "${file}"` in the `launch.json` actually refers to the file to be run and **not** the executable file path.

Selecting the python executable file is done from the settings under `default interpreter path` and `conda path` (for conda).

by changing both of the above parameters to the exe file name (in this case) `\\eu\tac\conda\1.0\win\envs\dev\CURRENT\python.exe` seemed to point `vscode` to the correct python exe.

For clarity, is a picture of where and how:
[image]